# Kafka producer on Intellij Idea giving syntax errors

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-kafka

THere is a producer code in .java file on intellij. There are several sytnax errors while code is being built like a missing ';' in statements of properties. Any help is appreciated.

THere is a producer.java file that has the code to produce messages. bootstrap server is assigned to a variable. The trainer is able to get past any issues, but, looks like I am stuck with 14 formatting errors - most of them being expected a stopper like ; or "not a statement".

```
package kafka.tutorial1;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;

import java.util.Properties;

public class ProducerDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String bootstrapServers = "127.0.0.1:9092";

        //create producer properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        Properties setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        Properties setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        Properties setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());

        //CREATE PRODUCER
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);

        //create producer record
        ProducerRecord<String, String> record =
                new ProducerRecord<String, String>("first_topic", "hello world");

        //send data
        producer.send(record);

    }
}
```

THe POM is as below -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>dattamza</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Comment: What error does IDE report? Can you build this class successfully?

Comment: It gives all syntax errors on IDE like the end of statements in between properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have

```
Properties setProperty(..., ...);
```

you mean

```
properties.setProperty(..., ...);
```

That is, you need to call the [`setProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method on the `Properties` instance that you created in the variable `properties`.

`Properties setProperty(..., ...);` does not make sense.